# Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, write pm2 server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pm2

I am not able to identify what is causing my ec2 disk space to reach 100% of capacity.
I have a script which deletes files in tmp folder.But still randomly sometimes my disk capacity reaches 100%.
I have attached the logs of df -i to show disk utilization.

**Error**

```
PM2        | Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, write
PM2        |     at Object.writeSync (fs.js:679:3)
PM2        |     at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1393:26)
PM2        |     at ProcessContainer (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js:70:10)
PM2        |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js:103:3)
PM2        |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
```

I am using command df -i to find
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**du -h -d 1**

Comment: So why not increase the size of your EBS volume?

Comment: yes we can, but i was interested in knowing what is causing the disk utilization to reach to max level @Marcin

Comment: Can you give result of ``du -sh /var``

Comment: $ sudo du -sh /var


3.1G   @Alaindeseine

Comment: @art Ok, but what i want is to see where bytes are, can you provide a screenshot of this command

Comment: @Alaindeseine last image contains that.

Comment: every thing seems fine. 7,7G seem to be a poorly disk space. Your logs and spool that i was suspected to be the problem are normal. logs are 800Mo, so you can reduce that now to get system healthy, but it will be saturated again quickly i guess. 
The best you have to do is increasing your / mout point?

Comment: @art Can you provide the content of the /opt directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dh` utility

```
cd /
du -h -d 1
```

it will show the disk usage for every folder in /, then you can `cd` in the biggest ones and repeat the same.

You can also run

```
du | sort -n
```

and you'll get (after a while) all the folders size in the filesystem (ordered by ascending size). By my experience I'd take a first look at /home, /tmp and /var.

Comment: i have added output of du -h -d 1 in question @gengisdave

Comment: take a look at /var/lib, /snap and /opt; /var/log could be cleaned, but you'll get a small amount of space (~5/10% of disk)

Comment: I can delete it manually but how can i not let it happen in future? @gengisdave

Comment: You can schedule log rotation / cleaning. Unless you found some cache or unused software to remove, I suggest a disk expansion as @Marcin said

Answer (score 3):

Check the user `.pm2/logs` directory, if your node app as errors or many regular logs this can increase disk space used.

I think that 8 Go is too small. I think you should upgrade your server to allocate more space. This will solved your problem.

If you can't or if you don't want to add disk space, you can take a look at the `/var/log` directory to delete some extra log. On long term, you can use logrotate to compress log files and upload compressed one to another place in order to keep `/var/log` as small a possible.

**UPDATE**

Also, i am not a specialist of ubuntu and snap, but your /snap directory is 2,1Go in size. You can check this to see if snap retain old version of snap package or if there is some cache that can be cleared.

Here is a bash script to remove old snaps version that i find here : https://www.debugpoint.com/clean-up-snap/

```
#!/bin/bash
 #Removes old revisions of snaps
 #CLOSE ALL SNAPS BEFORE RUNNING THIS
 set -eu
 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}' |
     while read snapname revision; do
         snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision"
     done
```

You can also delete files in `/var/lib/snapd/cache` it's a snap cache that can be cleared.

But as i say, not a specialist of Ubuntu, so not tested.

Comment: @art I update my answer